# Javascript / Jquery Help - Calling functions from select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Need some help with adding interactivity to this page.
I'm new to jQuery and this stuff is probably simple but its been driving me nuts!

Its just a footy team with different players details stored in objects in an array called Squad_list
**Squad_List.js**

```
var squad = [
  {
  number: 1,
  pic: 'img/HIBBERD_M_t.png',
  name: 'Michael',
  surname: 'Hibberd',
  height: '186 cm',
  weight: '86 kg',
  debut: 2011,
  position: ['defender'],
  games: 85,
  goals: 11  
  },
  {
  number: 2,
  pic: 'img/BELLCHAMBERS_T_t.png',
  name: 'Tom',
  surname: 'Bellchambers',
  height: '202 cm',
  weight: '106 kg',
  debut: 2008,
  position: ['ruck'],
  games: 79,
  goals: 53  
  },
  {
  number: 3,
  pic: 'img/CHAPMAN_P_t.png',
  name: 'Paul',
  surname: 'Chapman',
  height: '179 cm',
  weight: '87 kg',
  debut: 2000,
  position: ['foward'],
  games: 280,
  goals: 366,
  goals15: 8  
  },
];
```

etc etc

I have different functions to create a listQuery from the Squad_List based on different positions, games played etc ie addListDefender creates a list of players whose position = defender

I have a drawtable function to write the info to the page

I've got a select menu to pick the different listQuery options the values named after the relevant listQuery function it should call

**App.js**

```
var listQuery = [];


// Draw table from 'listQuery' array of objects
function drawTable(tbody) {
    var tr, td;
    tbody = document.getElementById(tbody);
    // loop through data source
    //    document.write(tbody);

    for (var i = 0; i < listQuery.length; i++) {
        tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.setAttribute("align", "center");
        td.innerHTML = "<p>" + listQuery[i].number + "</p>";
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = '<img src="' + listQuery[i].pic + '">';
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = listQuery[i].name + " " + listQuery[i].surname;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = listQuery[i].height;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = listQuery[i].weight;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = listQuery[i].debut;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        if  (listQuery[i].position.length > 1) { 
          td.innerHTML += listQuery[i].position[0] + " / " + listQuery[i].position[1]; 
          }  else {
          td.innerHTML += listQuery[i].position;
        }    
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = listQuery[i].games;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = listQuery[i].goals;
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
}

}


//Display entire list

var displayList = function() {
    listQuery = squad;
};


//Take players from list that position = foward

var addListFoward = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < squad.length; i++) {
    if (squad[i].position.indexOf("foward") >= 0) {
      listQuery.push(squad[i]);
      console.log(squad[i]);
    }  
  }
}


//Take players from list whose position = defender

var addListDefender = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < squad.length; i++) {
    if (squad[i].position === "defender") {
      listQuery.push(squad[i]);
      console.log(squad[i]);
    }
  }
}

//Take 10 items from player list in order of most games
var addListGames = function () {
  squad.sort(function(a, b){
     return b.games-a.games
  })
  listQuery = squad;
  listQuery.length = 10;
 }

// Site starts with Display Entire List
displayList();
drawTable("output");

//Generate list query on change select button from select options value

$('#select').change(function() {


});

//display selection from select button onclick go button

$('#go').click(function() {
//  alert("go has been click!");  

   drawTable("output");
});
```

Basically when the select menu is changed I want to call a function equal to the select value and then redraw the table with the go button.....but the various things I've tried on $('#select') and $('#go') don't work.

Any help much appreciated!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta cahrset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bombers Squad</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">  
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
  <div class="main-title">
    <h1>Bombers Squad</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo-2x.png" alt="Bombers logo">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main-field">
  <form>
  <label for="select">View Bombers Squad:</label>
  <select id="select" name="bombers_list">
    <option value="displayList">Display Entire List</option>
    <option value="addListFoward">Display Fowards</option>
    <option value="addListMidfield">Display Midfielders</option>
    <option value="addListDefender">Display Defenders</option>
    <option value="addListRuck">Display Rucks</option>
    <option value="addListGames">Display Most Games</option>
    <option value="addGoals2015">2015 Goal kickers</option>
    <option value="addBF2015">2015 Best & Fairest Votes</option>    
  </select>  
  <button id="go" type="submit">Go</button> 
  </form>  
  <table id="players">
    <caption>Player Information</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Number</th>
        <th scope="col">Picture</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>      
        <th scope="col">Height</th>   
        <th scope="col">Weight</th>   
        <th scope="col">Debut</th>   
        <th scope="col">Position</th>   
        <th scope="col">Games</th>  
        <th scope="col">Goals</th> 
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="output">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>  
<script src="js/squad_list.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

[JsFidder](http://jsfiddle.net/eL6Lv4aw/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you just forget to include jquery or not referenced properly

check the below [Answer & working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eL6Lv4aw/1/)

or simply add

```
$(function(){
$('#select').change(function () {


});

//display selection from select button onclick go button

$('#go').click(function () {
      alert("go has been click!");  

    drawTable("output");
});

})
```

Comment: Hey Kaushik Thanks for trying to help but its not working.   How do I make it call the addListFoward function when  $('#select')  is changed to Display Fowards?  I've tried various things like $('this').val but I cant get it to actually run the function. Not sure the go button is working properly either.  When Display Fowards is selected the only player that should display is Paul Chapman - When Display Defenders is selected the only player that should display is Michael Hibberd etc